# Spring Security: Error while upgrading the deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in Spring Boot 2.7.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to upgrade the spring boot version from 2.1.7.RELEASE to 2.7.2. After the version change I see the
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated. The current configuration looks like this.

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfigure extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "**/api/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "**/api/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(-1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());

        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();

       TransactionSynchronizationManager.setActualTransactionActive(true);
   }
}
```

After following this migration guide - [Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter), I've modified the code as below.

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfigure {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "**/api/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "**/api/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
            .disable().sessionManagement().maximumSessions(-1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());

        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();

        TransactionSynchronizationManager.setActualTransactionActive(true);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

After the change I'm getting this error while I start the application.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain. Please select just one.
```

I'm using the spring security oauth2 for enabling the SSO

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I highly doubt `@EnableOAuth2Sso` the reason behind the error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that you are using the [deprecated](https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/07/end-of-life-for-spring-security-oauth) spring-security-oauth module. Please migrate to a supported version of Spring Security as soon as possible. You can follow the official migration guide [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the exception show,because `@EnableOAuth2Sso` import `OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration` which it's extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.you can use dsl `http.oauth2Login()` instead of use `@EnableOAuth2Sso`